# Why does 'yum --disablerepo=\* list' still list items?

Tags: list, repository, yum

I am trying to set up a custom yum repo using Nexus. In order to test this, I am trying to list all of the items only in that repo, and not in any other repo that is set up on my machine. I am using RHEL 6.6.

The problem is, when i run `yum --disablerepo=\* list`, there are still hundreds of items that show up, and in the last column, the repos listed begin with an '@' symbol. How do I use this yum command to show literally nothing when I run list?

The reason I want to do this, is so that when I run `yum --disablerepo=\* list --enablerepo=<my_custom_repo>` it will show ONLY items from my repository, and nothing else at all.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `yum list` lists available and installed packages.

The packages you are seeing are the installed packages.

The `@` is the name of the repo they came from when they were installed (CentOS 5 didn't record that information and just said `installed` there).

To avoid listing them you want to use `yum list available` to only list available packages.

```
yum --disablerepo=* list available
```

and

```
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=custom-repo list available
```

(And yes, not escaping that asterisk is probably safe. You aren't likely to have files named `--disablerepo=<something>` in your current directory.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!